# Taylor series all terms up to the one in $x^{12}$, and calculating each coefficient as an integer or a fraction.

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find the taylor series about $0$ for the function $f(x) = e^{3(x^4)}$ giving all terms up to the one in $x^{12}$, and calculating each
coeficient as an integer or a fraction
 State an interval of validity for this series.

Comment: Consider the Taylor series of $e^t$ and replace $t$ by $3x^4$

Comment: What you've tried so far?